# Can I buy anything with coins?

Tags: new-super-luckys-tale

I know getting 300 coins in a level is one of the requirements for 100% in a level, but can I use the coins for anything? When I am in the overworld, I see a total of my coins. Is this like a score or can I buy anything with them?

Answer (score 1):

You can spend coins buying costumes. To buy a costume, look for a sign with a T-shirt icon.